# "&" and ".intersection()" difference?

Tags: python

I was wondering whether there is a difference between using "&" and ".intersection()" while finding the intersection of two sets in Python. If so, what are they?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection). Here is the main difference (**emphasis** is mine) :

> **Note, the non-operator versions** of union(), intersection(),
> difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset()
> methods **will accept any iterable as an argument.** In contrast, their
> operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This
> precludes error-prone constructions like set('abc') & 'cbs' in favor
> of the more readable set('abc').intersection('cbs').

Using the non operator function does not require to convert the iterable as a set.